# Can many people use a single account?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, best-practices, multiple-accounts

Can many people use a single SE account? This would lead to much faster accumulation of rep. It could also lead to certain posts being better than others (due to different authors), or even conflict between the shared users.

Of course, this can be done secretly and SE won't easily know about it, but is it okay to publicly announce that you are in fact, sharing your account with other persons?

**I don't plan on doing it myself, I'm just curious.**

P.S.

This Q would also include situations like a 10k rep user leaving his account to his son, who knows nothing about the site.